# Lock MySQL select row until UPDATE has been ran on it?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-order-by, where-clause

I have a table called `queue_items` that has 3 columns.

```
'item' varchar(500) the item that has been queued
'processed_at' a datetime to mark when it has started processing, and
'completed_at' a datetime to mark when it has completed in the queue worker
```

Here is how I am selecting items,

```
SELECT `id`,`item` FROM `queue_items` WHERE `processed_at` IS NULL AND `completed_at` IS NULL ORDER BY `id` ASC LIMIT 1
```

Once checking it exists and is valid to be processed, I run this:

```
UPDATE `queue_items` SET `processed_at` = @processedAt WHERE `id` = @id
```

The issue is, another queue worker can pick up the item that I just selected, before I update `processed_at`. How can I stop this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a transaction around the two queries, and use the `FOR UPDATE` option in the `SELECT` query to lock the rows that it examined. Any other connection that tries to read that row will be suspended until the transaction is committed.

Make sure you have an index on the columns you test in the `WHERE` clause, so it won't have to do a scan and lock all the rows it checked before finding the one you want.

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT @id := `id`,`item` 
FROM `queue_items` 
WHERE `processed_at` IS NULL AND `completed_at` IS NULL 
ORDER BY `id` ASC 
LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE `queue_items` SET `processed_at` = @processedAt WHERE `id` = @id

COMMIT;
```

Comment: I don't see the `FOR UPDATE` option in your answer, where am I supposed to place it? Also, what happens if a second instance tries to run the same query, does it just get the next row? Do I need to add any conditional checking in my application to count for this?

Comment: You don't see it on the line after `WHERE`?

Comment: Actually, that was the wrong place. It has to be after `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Sorry I posted that before you updated the question (or I might have missed it). Could you answer my latter question?

Comment: A second instance will be blocked until the transaction completes. At that time, this row will be updated, and it will get the next row.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single query. Use `update` with a row-limiting clause:

```
UPDATE `queue_items` 
SET `processed_at` = @processedAt 
WHERE `processed_at` IS NULL AND `completed_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY id LIMIT 1
```

If you want to retain the `id` of the row that was updated, it is a bit tricky. MySQL does not support the `RETURNING` clause, but we can work around this with a user variable:

```
SET @updated_id := 0;

UPDATE `queue_items` 
SET `processed_at` = @processedAt, id = (@x := id)
WHERE `processed_at` IS NULL AND `completed_at` IS NULL
ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;

@SELECT @updated_id;
```

Comment: Sure, but how do I get the item of the record I updated at the same time? Otherwise I won't know which item to process on the worker. If I use a query for the last updated ID and fetch it that way another worker could have updated a record since which lands me in the same spot.

Comment: Thanks! So does this disallow two workers fetching the same queue item, even with a multi-core MySQL server?

Comment: @asynclife: this is safe from concurrency perspective, since the operation is performed in a single statement (instead of two in your original attempt) - and, of course, user variables are private to the session.

Comment: I have tried to execute this in datagrip to test, and the variable `updated_id` always returns 0? I have checked the row and it seems to update `processed_at` accordingly.

Comment: Updated: fixed it by changing `@x` to the correct variable name

Comment: For anyone who is using C# and stumbles across this answer, make sure you set `AllowUserVariables` to true in your connection string, or it will throw an exception due to a parameter not being defined.

Comment: @asynclife: I am curious to know why you unaccepted this answer.