# Stop two rows being accessed at the same time with MySQL InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb

This is a sequel to my previous question, which didn't fix the issue 100%. Find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63662032/lock-mysql-select-row-until-update-has-been-ran-on-it)

I have an InnoDB MySQL database, this database is accessed from 10 - 20 external services. I have noticed that multiple services are pulling in the same row from the `queue_items` table, how can I stop this happening?

Here is how I fetch a queue item in my application,

```
dbConnection.SetQuery(@"
    SET @updated_id := 0;

    UPDATE `queue_items`
    SET `processed_at` = @processedAt, `worker_id` = @workerId, id = (@updated_id := id)
    WHERE `processed_at` IS NULL AND `completed_at` IS NULL AND `confirmed` = '1'" + (onlyPublic ? " AND `is_private` = '0'" : "") +
    @"ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;

    SELECT @updated_id;");
```

I then follow that up with a `SELECT WHERE ID` query with the result from the first query with the value of `@updated_id`.

Raw query,

```
SET @updated_id := 0;

UPDATE `queue_items`
SET `processed_at` = @processedAt, `worker_id` = @workerId, id = (@updated_id := id)
WHERE `processed_at` IS NULL AND `completed_at` IS NULL AND `confirmed` = '1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1;

SELECT @updated_id;
```

Comment: I suspect what you're looking for is the `FOR UPDATE` option to `SELECT`.

Comment: This won't block other processes from reading the row, but they won't be able to update it until you commit your transaction.

Comment: @Barmar because it worked (or I thought it did) at the time. All it really did was reduce the chance of a duplicate record being fetched.

Comment: I added an answer to the first question.

Comment: When you say it will block the process from updating it, what exactly happens when you try and update it? Will my current query just result in `@updated_at` becoming 0? Or does MySQL wait for the transaction to be commited, and then allow them to update the row?

Comment: See my answer in the original question.

Comment: I was wrong above. It does block them from reading the row until the transaction is committed.

Comment: The whole point is that it makes the `SELECT+UPDATE` an atomic operation.